# Spring injecting an interface implementation gives Nullpointer

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-security

I am very new to Spring and Spring security!

After following some tutorials I am now trying to implement Spring Security into our application. The problem I am having is that I want to test my class `UserDetailsImpl` with stubs. Therefor I would like Spring to inject 2 objects as stubs that I have created (they implement from an interface). This way, when I run my test, the stubs will get implemented, but during production code, the normal real implementations will be injected. unfortunately I get a `NullPointerException`. This is my code:

The class that has to be injected:

```
package com.somePackageName.security;

imports...

@Component
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

@Autowired
IUserFactory userFactory;

public void setUserFactory(IUserFactory userFactory){
    this.userFactory = userFactory;
}

@Autowired
IUser user;

public void setUser(IUser user){
    this.user = user;
}
```

IUser & IUserFactory are interfaces.

This is the `IUserFactory` stub that I want to implement:

```
package com.somePackageName;

import com.su.rbac.virtuoso.IUser;
import com.su.rbac.virtuoso.IUserFactory;

public class StubUserFactory implements IUserFactory {

public StubUserFactory(){}

@Override
public IUser findUserWithUsername(String username) {
    return new StubUser();
}

@Override
public IUser createUser(String username, String password) {
    return new StubUser();
}
}
```

And finally my `application-context.xml` file:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.somePackageName" />

<beans:bean id="userDetailsImpl" class="com.somePackageName.security.UserDetailsImpl">
    <!--
    <beans:property name="userFactory" value="com.somePackageName.StubUserFactory"/>
    <beans:property name="user" value="com.somePackageName.StubUser"/>
    -->

    <beans:property name="userFactory" ref="StubUserFactory"/>
    <beans:property name="user" ref="StubUser"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="StubUser" class="com.somePackageName.StubUser"/>
<beans:bean id="StubUserFactory" class="com.somePackageName.StubUserFactory"/>
```

The error that I"m getting is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.somePackageName.security.UserDetailsImpl.<init>(UserDetailsImpl.java:44)
at com.somePackageName.security.QuadstoreUserService.loadUserByUsername(QuadstoreUserService.java:23)
at com.somePackageName.SpringSecurityTest.firstTest(SpringSecurityTest.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I am really stuck on this one, as I can't seem to find a good and clear example on the internet. I very much thank you in advance!

Comment: You have a typo in the bean id: `userDeatilsImpl ` (don't know yet, if that's the problem though).

Comment: Bean id shouldn't matter unless he's using it somewhere.

Comment: Haha wow I feel so stupid! Thanks. Still the same message error though

Comment: @Lenymm: true. Rens: Are you sure the class is considered for autowiring (e.g. by using the [@Component](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)) annotation)?

Comment: Thanks Wolfram, I didn't know that was necessary! I added it now to the UserDetailsImpl. Nothing has changed though.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have annotations enabled, try adding:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="<your_package_name>,<your_another_package_name>" />
```

xmlns:

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

xsi schema location:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
```

Comment: I've added both xmlns and xsi for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have read some documentation about it. I can see that I need it, but even though I added it, nothing has changed... Hmm

Comment: Try to add @Component annotation to your UserDetailsImpl.

Comment: Also just did that, I have edited my question so my the code is applied as I have it now

Comment: And it still doesn't work? If so then check your conf files... you might have more of them and you need to figure out where to put the component scan tag.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure it out some more ;) When I know it I will answer my question :) Thanks for the effort though :)

Comment: I have one doubt, if you have used @component annotation to register your UserDetailsImpl bean and autowired annotation for wiring, why are you explicitly defining the bean in xml config as well ?